# How to check if I am inside the WP Theme Customizer preview?

Tags: template-tags, theme-customizer

I have some elements showing on the home page that I do not want to display in the Theme Customizer preview window. Is there a simple check in PHP that I can use for that ?

For example:

```
<img class="background" src="<?php echo $background ?>" <?php if(is_wpThemeCustomizer()) echo 'style="display:none"' ?>/>
```

I could do it in javascript using the js file that is enqueued only in this case, but I would like to use PHP, or even better : CSS. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check for global variable `$wp_customize`:

```
if ( empty ( $GLOBALS['wp_customize'] ) ) 
{
    // show something
}
```

**Update:** in WordPress 4.0, you can use [`is_customize_preview()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/28999).

Answer (score 2):

### Alternatively

```
global $wp_customize;
if (isset($wp_customize)) {
     // do stuff
}
```

Comment: This is actually the same way.

Comment: Not sure about downvotes. The answer is correct! Same as toscho but correct answer and cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

From Wordpress 4.0 you can use [is_customize_preview();](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_customize_preview)

Answer (score 1):

AS shared by iki, here is a simple example to add something conditionally, if currently on customizer preview page:

```
if (is_customize_preview()) {
    // perform customizer specific action
} else {
    // perform separate action
}
```